# Command contains pipe characters - why is vim saying "not an editor command"?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm trying to map some commands to a shortcut in vim. Specifically, I'm trying to get a colorized git diff. If I type this command in Ex mode, it works as expected:

`:! git diff --staged % | colordiff | less -R`

But if I try to map it in my .vmirc,

`map ,gds :! git diff --staged % | colordiff | less -R<CR>`

I get the error:

`E492: Not an editor command: colordiff | less -R<CR>`

I have other mapped commands using a pipe just fine, so it doesn't seem like that should cause a problem. If I call colordiff by its full path, it doesn't help, either. What gives?

Comment: You should take advantage of vimdiff mode as the plugins such as CVSmenu.
Otherwise, have you tried `\|` instead ?

Comment: D'oh! `\|` did it. I figured it was something stupid. I'll check out CVSmenu, but you should put your comment as an answer, so I can give you credit. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(OK, here it is -- I wasn't sure about `\|`)

Try `\|` instead of `|`.

But you should instead have a look at the vimdiff mode, and how plugins like CVSmenu proceed. BTW, IIRC there already exists a (likely several) plugin that integrates git into vim.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Luc's answer, this is because `|` is the command separator in vim, similar to `;` in bash